# How to optimize my code to minimize program execution time

Tags: java

I am trying to solve a problem and I wrote the solution, but apparently the program takes too long to run. How do I minimize the running time of it?

This is the problem I'm solving:

[Pebble Solitaire](https://academicwork.kattis.com/problems/pebblesolitaire2)

And this is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PebbleSolitaire {

    private static int maxDigits = 1 << 23;
    private static int[] posSol = new int[maxDigits];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        int cases = reader.nextInt();
        reader.nextLine();

        for (int caseCount = 0; caseCount < cases; caseCount++) {
            int lineInt = 0;
            String lineStr = reader.nextLine().trim();

            for (int i = 0; i < lineStr.length(); i++) {
                if (lineStr.charAt(i) == 'o') {
                    lineInt |= (1 << i);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < maxDigits; i++) {
                posSol[i] = -1;
            }

            System.out.println(calculateLeastPebbles(lineInt));
        }
    }

    private static int calculateLeastPebbles(int lineInt) {
        if (posSol[lineInt] != -1) {
            return posSol[lineInt];
        }

        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
            if ((lineInt & (1 << i)) != 0) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
            if (i >= 2 && ((lineInt ^ (3 << (i - 2))) & (7 << (i - 2))) == 0) {
                counter = Math.min(counter, calculateLeastPebbles(lineInt ^ (7 << (i - 2))));
            }
            if (i <= 20 && ((lineInt ^ (6 << i)) & (7 << i)) == 0) {
                counter = Math.min(counter, calculateLeastPebbles(lineInt ^ (7 << i)));
            }
        }

        return counter;
    }
}
```

What can I do to make it faster?

Comment: Ad first I'd try to remove the bit shifting stuff and replaces that with something more readable. Maybe this improves something. Beside this you should instrument your code for timing measurement (either grammatically or by a framework) to spot the bottleneck.

Comment: You could cache results with a `Map<Integer, Integer>` at the end of `calculateLeastPebbles` and put a lookup in the beginning.

Comment: question was not clear about asking solution